# Increment all values in a Map by 1

Tags: java, lambda, hash-map

What's the neatest way to increment all values in a `HashMap` by 1? The map is `<String, Integer>`, but the key doesn't matter as every value will be incremented.

Is it "cleaner" to use lambdas with `forEach`/`compute`/etc. or just loop through the entries?

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = mobCounter.get(mob);
for (Entry<String, Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
    map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue() + 1);
}
```

This doesn't look too messy to me but I'm wondering if people like seeing lambdas more.

Comment: Unless you are specifically bound to use HashMap, you could write `Map<String, Integer> map = mobCounter.get(mob);` instead of `HashMap`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must not modify the keys of a `HashMap` while iterating over it. You are just lucky it worked.

Instead of the `put(...)`, write `e.setValue(e.getValue() + 1)`.

If you have some kind of `Multiset` available (e.g. when you are using Guava), you could replace your `HashMap` with a `Multiset<String>`, which will make your intention clearer.

Using lambdas, your code would look like:

```
map.replaceAll((k, v) -> v + 1);
```

This looks very nice to me. It cannot get any shorter.

Comment: Never knew that, thank you! The `replaceAll` does look very clean, I'll use that. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The solution you've offered is a perfectly fine solution.  While it is possible to do it with lambdas, I don't think it's strictly necessary.

The only things I would mention:

- `map` is a terrible name for a variable.
- Your `map` variable should have the interface type, not the implementation type.